# WPF render Blur Image

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Currently i'm showing an icon in my application. The issue that i'm facing is that it shows image blur. Here is the snapshot of original icon (Zoomed Version).

**Original Icon Image**

[image: Original Icon Image (Zoomed)]

**Solutions Tried so Far**

**Solution 1: WPF Rendered Image With SnapstoDevicePixel=False**

[image: WPF Rendered Image With SnapstoDevicePixel=False]

**Solution 2: WPF Rendered Image With SnapstoDevicePixel=True**

[image: WPF Rendered Image With SnapstoDevicePixel=True]

**Solution 3: WPF Rendered Image with RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"**

[image: WPF Rendered Image with RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased]

At the moment the better result i'm getting is using RenderOptions, but the issue is that it shows first bar bit bolder. Your help will be appreciated.

P.S: Ignore the size of image at the moment.

Comment: `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" ` Should do the trick just make sure your `Image.Width` and `Image.Height` are equal to bitmap dimensions.

Comment: @ghord width and height are same as the image dimensions.

Comment: try `Image.Stretch="None"`

Comment: @ghord it didn't worked :(

Answer (score 1):

Try RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"